How to find a matrix, characteristic and minimal polynomial of a linear operator?
Given linear operator: $L : \mathbb{R}^3[X] → \mathbb{R}^3[X]$
$$L(g(X))=g(0)(-1-2X+4X^2)+g^`(1)(-1+2X^2)+g^{``}(0)(-X+\frac{1}{2}X^2)$$
Find the matrix of operator L, characteristic and minimal polynomials. Given basis: $e=[1, X, X^2]$
My calculation of the matrix:
Let us set $g(X) = a + bX + cX^2$. Next, we would calculate $g'$ and $g''$ in terms of $a, b, c$ and it would look like this after simplifying:
$$L(g(X))= a(-1-2X+4X^2) + b(-1+2X^2) +c(-2-2X+5X^2)$$ (this is the result after we plugged in the values of $g(0), g'(1), g''(0)$ and simplifying the equation). Now, plug in the values multiplied by a, b and c accordingly into the basis. In other words, now $L(e_1) = -1-2X+4X^2$, $L(e_2)= -1+2X^2$ and $L(e_3)= -2-2X+5X^2$. These we sort into columns and that's how the matrix is made.
$$ A = \begin{pmatrix}
-1 & -1 &  -2\\
-2 & 0 &  -2\\
4 & 2 & 5 \\
\end{pmatrix}$$
So, characteristic polynomial will be to find $A-\lambda E; E$ being a diagonal matrix $\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{pmatrix}$.
Further, we have $det(A-\lambda E)$ and that's how we get a characteristic polynomial.
So characteristic polynomial will be in a form of $(X-\lambda_1)\cdot(X-\lambda_2)\cdot(X-\lambda_3)$
Next, we have
$$ det(A-\lambda E) = \begin{vmatrix}
-1-\lambda & -1 & -2 \\
-2 & 0 - \lambda & -2 \\
4 & 2 & 5- \lambda \\ 
\end{vmatrix}$$
And characteristic polynomial from here is $(\lambda-1)^2 \cdot(\lambda-2)$
Not sure about minimal polynomial but I got it to be:
$(\lambda-1)\cdot(\lambda-2)$
and the eigenvalues (or characteristic values) are $1$ and $2$

First, write down the matrix representation of $L$ with respect to the chosen basis. Then find the characteristic polynomial of that matrix. Finally, you may check, by trial and error, which divisor of the characteristic polynomial is the minimal polynomial.

I looked some youtube videos that taught me how to find a minimal polynomial (by inserting $(A-1E)$ instead of $(\lambda -1)$ etc.) and after that multiplying these two matrices should tell me if its a zero matrix. If that's not the case, then the minimal polynomial is equal to the characteristic polynomial. As for the question, I have none since all have been answered partially on this site, partially from other sources so the step by step process is shown (for other people with similar questions) on how to find everything that was my initial question.

If so, in order to remove your post from the list of non-answered question, I suggest you remove your recent progress from the question and post them instead as a self-answer. But leave some previous progress (for instance: the finally correct calculation of the matrix, or at least the first step) in the question, so that it cannot be closed for lack of effort. And if you are now sure about the minimal polynomial, better don't write you are not. You could also delete the obsolete comments.

'So both characteristic and minimal polynomials will be in a form of $(X-\lambda_1)\cdot(X-\lambda_2)\cdot(X-\lambda_3)$, $X \in A$' is doubly false: there should be no '$X \in A$' ($X$ is just the polynomial indeterminate), and the minimal polynomial will ultimately be found to be of degree 2, not 3.

Please, avoid having your question become a chameleon question. It was answered. If you have a new question, publish a new post, with some efforts on it (and a link to this one). I rolled back.

In this case an opportunistic approach to find the minimal polynomial directly is actually easier than computing the characteristic polynomial. The idea is to compute repeated images by $L$ of some vector, and while doing so to find a linear dependence among them; once one is found this gives a polynomial in $L$ that vanishes on the initial vector, but in fact also on its images; with some luck it vanishes everywhere. I'll take as initial vector the polynomial $X$, since this makes the computation a bit simpler. One has
$$ \def\arr{\quad\overset{L}\mapsto\quad}
  X \arr -1+X^2 \arr -3-2X+6X^2,
$$
at which point we can recognise the linear relation $0=2X-3L(X)+L(L(X))=(2L^0-3L^1+L^2)(X)$, giving a polynomial $P=2-3Y+Y^2$ (I'm using $Y$ as indeterminate to avoid confusion with an element of the vector space $\Bbb R[X]_{<3}$ that $L$ operates on) such that the linear operator $P[L]=2L^0-3L^1+L^2$ vanishes on the initial vector $X$. However, since the kernel of $P[L]$ is an $L$-stable subspace (this is true for all polynomials in $L$), that kernel also contains $L(X)$, and $L^k(X)$ for any $k\in\Bbb N$. But those powers are all contained in the subspace generated by just $X$ and $L(X)$, so to know whether $P[L]$ vanishes everywhere we must apply it to a vector not in that $2$-dimensional subspace. The easiest choice is the constant polynomial $1=X^0$, for which we have
$$ 
  1 \arr -1-2X+4X^2 \arr -5-6X+12X^2,
$$
and one can check that $(2L^0-3L^1+L^2)(1)=0$ as well. Therefore $P[L]$ vanishes on the whole space (since $[X,L(X),1]$ is a generating family of vectors) and $P$ is the minimal polynomial.
To find the characteristic polynomial$~\chi$, one needs to find the roots of $P$, which are $1$ and $2$ (the absence of multiple roots for $P$ already tells us that $L$ is diagonalisable), and their multiplicities as roots of$~\chi$ (which should sum to$~3$, the dimension, so one of them is a double root). Knowing that $A$ is diagonalisable, we can find the multiplicity of $\lambda\in\{1,2\}$ as the geometric multiplicity $\dim(\ker(A-\lambda I))$; one easily checks that $A-I$ is of rank$~1$ while $A-2I$ is of rank$~2$, so the multiplicity of $\lambda=1$ as root of$~\chi$ is $3-1=2$, and that of $\lambda=2$ is $3-2=1$. We conclude that $\chi=(Y-1)^2(Y-2)=Y^3-4Y^2+5Y-2$.
[Clearly you made an error in computing the characteristic polynomial.]

Interesting solution, but imo really not 'easier' that the usual one. And the exercise began with 'Find the matrix of operator L'.

The OP did indeed numerous errors in their consecutive edits, but I can see none remaining 'in computing the characteristic polynomial'. Or do you just mean the change of convention from $\det(A-\lambda E)$ to $\det(\lambda E-A)$?

@AnneBauval The matrix was already (correctly) computed in the question, so I don't see what I need to add to that in my answer. I start by saying my method is opportunistic, implying it is not always easier than computing the characteristic polynomial first; however if the minimal polynomial is actually of lower degree (as I suspected it would be here) then it may be easier. Note that I neither needed to compute a determinant of polynomials nor factor a polynomial of degree $3$, both of which are not trivial. And I note that the question has been corrected since I started to write my answer.
